# joomla native function building multi-level category

Tags: joomla2.5

How to output a category like this using joomla native function. I am not using xml form to output the

```
Category 1
  Category 9
    Category 15
    Category 16
    Category 17
    Category ...
    Category 24
  Category 10
    etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe you need this function `JHtmlMenu::treerecurse($id, $indent, $list, $children, $maxlevel = 9999, $level = 0, $type = 1)`.
You can find this function in this file /libraries/joomla/html/html/menu.php. This function can prepare a tree, but you need prepare template manually.